# Internacionalización con i18n

Tags: reactjs, i18n

estoy utilizando la libreria de i18n-js para internacionalizar mi aplicación web.

Mi problema es que hay componentes que se actualizan correctamente y otros que no. }

Para cambiar de un lenguaje a otro estoy utilizando un selector, éste funciona perfectamente, tiene 2 botones, uno español y otro para portugues. Cada uno apuntando a su respectiva traduccion, cambiando el `i18n.locale`.

```
  const changeToSpanish = () => {
    i18n.locale = 'es';
    dispatch(SetLanguage(i18n.locale));
    localStorage.setItem('LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE', 'es');
  };

  const changeToPortuguese = () => {
    i18n.locale = 'pt';
    dispatch(SetLanguage(i18n.locale));
    localStorage.setItem('LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE', 'pt');
  };
```

El problema es en el siguiente componente:

```
const columns: TableColumns[] = [
  {
    id: "created_at",
    label: i18n.t('app.Alta'),
    render: (value: any, record: any) => {
      return <>{formatDate(value) || "-"}</>;
    },
    width: 100,
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    id: "input_weight",
    label: i18n.t('app.Peso'),
    width: 100,
    render: (value) => (
      <span>{value ? <CustomNumericFormat value={value} /> : "-"}</span>
    ),
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    id: "lots_country_sides",
    label: i18n.t('app.Establecimiento'),
    render: (value: any, record: any) => {
      return <>{record.lots_country_sides?.name || "-"}</>;
    },
    width: 250,
    sortable: true,
  },
    width: 250,
    sortable: true,
  }
  { id: "acciones", label: "Acciones", width: "5%" },
];
```

`columns` pertenece a una tabla, y los `app.x` son los nombres de las columnas. Éstas columnas, cuando hago el cambio de lenguaje, no se están actualizando, y nosé porqué es.

El valor predeterminado de `i18n.locale` es `"es"`, por lo que la web empieza en Español. Si `i18n.locale` le establezco como predeterminado "pt", es decir portugues, el componente mostrado se muestra en portugues.

Acá se utiliza `columns`

```
 const customColumns: TableColumns<ISilobags>[] = [
    {
      id: "",
      label: "",
      render: (value: any, record) => {
        const color = record.partially_extracted
          ? "#FD7E14"
          : !record.active
          ? "#7A7A7A"
          : "#6BAA00";
        return <DotComponent color={color} />;
      },
      width: 5,
    },
    {
      id: "name",
      label: "Silo",
      render: (value: any, record: any) => {
        const openViewMode = () => goToView(record);
        return (
          <button
            className="silo-bag-link d-inline-flex align-center"
            style={{
              gap: 5,
              textAlign: "initial",
              lineHeight: "17px",
            }}
            onClick={openViewMode}
          >
            <span>{value}</span>
            <img
              src={ChevronRight}
              alt="chrevronright"
              style={{ width: 10, height: 10 }}
            />
          </button>
        );
      },
      width: 400,
    },
    ...columns,
  ];
```

Y `customColumns` se utiliza en el componente

```
  return (
    <CardComponent
      title
      dashboard
      bodyClassName="table-padding-top-0 silobag--list"
      minHeight={676}
      marginTop={"0"}
      style={{ width: "100%", minHeight: 676 }}
    >
      {siloBagData.loading || localLoading ? (
        <Spinner
          className="loading-spinner administrator"
          animation="border"
          role="status"
        ></Spinner>
      ) : (
        <CustomTable
          columns={customColumns}
          values={silobags}
          actions={{
            edit: true,
            view: true,
            map: { canDisable: true },
            delete: false,
            downloadPdf: true,
          }}
          onActionClick={handleActionClick}
          pagination
        />
      )}
    </CardComponent>
  );
```

[image: Un vistazo de como se ve la web]